# Temporarily suspended for swearing?

Tags: discussion, chat, account-suspension

Since when did this become a rule?

I posted a link to a server deployment site I saw on HN, it got flagged for whatever reason.

I then got suspended for the following message:

> Why the fuck was that flagged?

I've used expletives many times with multiple moderators in the room with no action.

If you check the link below, there are more than 13k messages containing a single swear word with no action taken.

> https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?room=17&q=fuck

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice

Comment: But that seems subjective, as I said many other moderators have been okay with that sort of language.

Comment: You have been lucky so far then.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/31251058#31251058

Comment: Kinda mystifying.  Maybe the cognitive dissonance is caused by the term "chat room".  Users don't seem to understand that it doesn't resemble a room at all and everybody in the entire world can hear what they say.  "chat forum"?

Comment: The above chat message is from a moderator, so I still don't have a clear answer on what is allowed and what isn't.

Comment: You do have an answer. It is not allowed. As simple as that. That you get away with it on occasion, that not everyone who uttered the same word got banned, or whatever you want to drag in as examples doesn't matter. You can't swear, and if you do, you run the risk of being banned.

Comment: I don't find it necessary to use swear words *ever* in an environment that is not your own private property, but *come on*... kids of 7-8 commonly yell the F word at each other nowadays. Apparently its not bad enough anymore to be reprimanded for it.

Comment: Why doesn't SE systematically filter common vulgarity? They've already done that with [common greetings/salutations.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/348113)

Answer (score 37):

*Technically*, swearing is not permitted anywhere on Stack Exchange: see [Are expletives (cursing, swear words or vulgar language) allowed on SE sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22232/262823) There's also a rule that you have to [Be Nice](/help/be-nice), which is [replicated in the chat FAQ](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq#nice).

There is a slightly higher tolerance in chat, since it's a "third place" and where many people go to relax and be social. However, be aware that if a moderator - or six 10k users - consider your message offensive, you can be suspended for it.

Moderation also depends on *context* - swearing in some contexts is far less offensive than in others.

But yes, it's still hit and miss. As far as "not being suspended for it before" goes, you've been lucky.